# Probability Question - Number of boxes one should look at

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Will someone help me understand how to solve the following ?

Jenny has 10 boxes all containing clothes. She is looking for her white pants, but has the following problem: while searching, she can only remember the last box she looked at. That is, it may be that she will search again the same box, but not continuously. In every step she chooses a box randomly between the possible boxes at this stage.

What is the probability the she will find the pants in the fifth box she will look at ?

Thanks in advance!

The only thing I could think about is that the probability is a conditional one, that the box is not in the fourth box she looked at but it is in the fifth box she looked at. Unfortunately, the calculation went bad, and it seems like this is not the way to solve this question. Will someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if my reasoning is correct but consider it:
Getting it in the fifth box is the same as not getting it in the first four and getting it in the fifth, denote P the required probability:
\begin{equation}
P=\frac{9}{10}* (\frac{8}{9})^3 *\frac{1}{9}= \frac{256}{3645}
\end{equation}
this yields an approximate answer of 0.07 which seems a bit small to me…
Please correct me if you can.

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks a lot !